# Как можно завершить процесс выполнения программы?

Tags: c++, файлы, поток-ввода

Как можно завершить процесс выполнения программы, если указанного для потока ввода файла не существует?

Comment: [man 2 exit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit), а еще лучше [man 3 err](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выйти из функции `main` используя оператор `return`. Наличие файла можно проверить так:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fo = fopen("Путь к файлу", "r");
    // Файла нет
    if (fo == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Технически ошибка на этом этапе означает скорее, что "файл нельзя прочитать". Он может существовать, просто быть недоступен. Хотя задач, где различать эти ситуации важно, очень мало.

Comment: @D-side а как можно узнать, когда не существует, а когда не доступен?

Comment: @nikita портируемо -- никак. ОС может намеренно обеспечивать такую иллюзию.

Comment: @nikita, если используем `fopen`, то скорее всего подразумеваем, чт исполняем программу в `POSIX`. А там есть глобальная перменная `errno` (доступна через `#include <errno.h>`). Если она равна `ENOENT`, то нет такого файла. (все ее значения, относящиеся к делу, можно посмотреть в **man 2 open**)

Comment: Все же `return 0;`, как-то нехорошо, поскольку 0 это **код нормального** завершения процесса.

Comment: @avp, вы правы, поправил